# WAMP doesn't refresh files

Tags: file, symfony, wamp, refresh

I've been working with WAMP for 2 years now and it's the first time I got this problem. I created a new website base with Symfony, and now I'm adding some files to it in Windows (by creating a bundle in a console) but it doesn't appear in the browser in localhost even I refresh it, so when I go in /web, I got those errors like these :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SNS\PlatformBundle\SNSPlatformBundle' not found in D:\wamp\www\sns_symfony\sns_symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 20
( ! ) Error: Class 'SNS\PlatformBundle\SNSPlatformBundle' not found in D:\wamp\www\sns_symfony\sns_symfony\app\AppKernel.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  385736  {main}( )   ...\app.php:0
2   0.0070  418000  AppKernel->handle( )    ...\app.php:19
3   0.0070  418000  AppKernel->boot( )  ...\Kernel.php:195
4   0.0070  418000  AppKernel->initializeBundles( ) ...\Kernel.php:132
5   0.0070  417952  AppKernel->registerBundles( )   ...\Kernel.php:492
```

Can someone help me please ? ^^'

I'll explain myself more. I used the bundle generator of Symfony so I dind't write anything, juste used the console. By the way there is some folders that WAMP can't see (I don't see them in the browser in localhost) and the file he's looking for are in those folders he can't see. There is the problem.

Comment: Did you import the specified class with a `use` statement?

Comment: @EmanuelOster I'll explain myself more. I used the bundle generator of Symfony so I dind't write anything, juste used the console. By the way there is some folders that WAMP can't see (I don't see them in the browser in localhost) and the file he's looking for are in those folders he can't see. There is the problem.

Comment: Can you check that it is not simply a file permissions issue? When you use commands to generate stuff, it might assign different permissions, than when you manually create the files in the IDE.

Comment: @adsc I checked it and I changed it for all users but doesn't work anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, double check if the bundle really exists on your hard drive. You're on Windows, so just go to `D:\wamp\www\sns_symfony\sns_symfony\src` and check if there's a `PlatformBundle\SNSPlatformBundle.php` in your `src` dir. If not - now you know the generator didn't generate anything. Maybe accidentally aborted?

Then check if you have right PSR-0 or PSR-4 (most likely ) namespace in your `composer.json` file. You can run `php composer validate` to see warnings.

And as the last step run `composer dump-autoload` which updates the autoload file

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Did all of that but unfortunately it doesn't work. I changed the PSR-4 for nothing like :
    "": "src/"
And now I have the following error :

    Twig_Error_Loader
    There are no registered paths for namespace "SNSPlatformBundle".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution after hours of deeps researches. Here it is :

- Create the bundle
- Edit your app/config/config.yml file like (add templating: engines ['twig'] in framework:)

  framework:
      templating:
          engines: ['twig']

Thanks for help people ! :D

SOLVED !